# Bulk addition of list items, with single approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, excel

I have received a very strange request from the business teams. They want to move their manual approval process to issue an approval letter from Email currently to SharePoint O365. So I created a list with 10 fields which capture all the required information, including the names of approvers. I am then using a Workflow to process the item through three layers of approvers.

All good and fine till here, but I just hit a roadblock. They want the ability to upload or raise bulk requests. Which means, they will collate all the requests they receive in email and put it in an Excel and then copy-paste it to SharePoint in DataSheet view.

Now, I can use multi line columns to achieve this as well - that way I am able to add up to 40 lines in each column. But then, the business also needs to do analysis on this after exporting the information in Excel.

So, I am in a catch-22 situation. I cannot run a work flow 40 times, nor can I add it in bulk because I wont be able to convert all multi line columns into different rows in Excel...

What solution can I look at?

Answer (score 0):

For similar issues we have used CSOM + xml. The process was to create an xml file from excel file. (refer this link for more information https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-XML-data-file-and-XML-schema-file-from-worksheet-data-e35400d4-0e10-4669-9a50-59a8c57d677e ). Using CSOM coding, crate upload control and browse the xml. Save the xml file in document library, read it , process it and create new item in list using CSOM coding.